# Intellij Complete - Editor Tabs not formatted

Tags: intellij-idea

I just downloaded the Complete version of IntelliJ, 
I imported my settings from the community version.
I checked in the editor tab settings, nothing craz going on.

I tried changing the position but still it had issues...

But my editor tabs are not showing correctly, cany anyone help?[image: the yellow bar is the bottom of the tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, this was fixed with an update to the Materials Plugin. Make sure to keep updated!